# How to get count based on collection and using multiple element-word-query with XQuery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Trying to get count of cars based on different filters and within one collection. Even though we see multiple cars that meet the requirement, the query is returning count 0.

```
fn:count(cts:search(fn:collection("com.cars"), cts:and-query((
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("exteriorColor"),  "red", "wildcarded" ),
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("interiorColor"),  "gray", "wildcarded" )
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("powerSteering"),  json:null(), "wildcarded" )
    ))))
```

Test Data:

```
{
      "id":1
      "carName":"Toyoto",
      "exteriorColor": "red",
      "interiorColor": "gray",
      "powerStreering": null
    }
    {
      "id":2
      "carName":"Toyoto",
      "exteriorColor": "blue",
      "interiorColor": "gray",
      "powerStreering": null
    }
    {
      "id":3
      "carName":"Toyoto",
      "exteriorColor": "red",
      "interiorColor": "gray",
      "powerStreering": "yes"
    }
    {
      "id":4
      "carName":"Toyoto",
      "exteriorColor": "white",
      "interiorColor": "gray",
      "powerStreering": null
    }
    {
      "id":5
      "carName":"Toyoto",
      "exteriorColor": "red",
      "interiorColor": "gray",
      "powerStreering": null
    }
```

Comment: What do the documents look like? Are you sure they are in the `com.cars` collection? `json:null()` evaluates to the empty sequence when passed this way - is that what you intended?

Comment: Documents are JSON type (edited question with the data). They are all in ```com.cars``` collection. I'm trying to get count of cars that have exteriorColor red and interiorColor gray and powerStreering is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `cts:element-word-query` when you need to be using `cts:json-property-word-query` instead: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:json-property-word-query

To test for null, I believe you should be using:

```
cts:json-property-value-query("propertyName", json:null())
```

Comment: Plus at scale you’ll need xdmp:estimate instead of fn:count.